# Store alias_primary_connection_string in keyvault under service bus queue SAS policy

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I want to store "**alias_primary_connection_string"** from each queue SAS policy of a defined service bus namespace in Keyvault secret using PowerShell in azure. Tried using Get-AzServiceBusNamespace & Get-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRule with for loop but not able to achieve it. I am getting name of all queues name but not alias_primary_connection_string. Need help on the code.

Tried below and got all the queue in namespace.
I want to store each queue's alias_primary_connection_string one by one in the keyvault secret with name like ("each queue name" append with string "alias_primary_string" ) and if  entry already present in keyvault then override it or delete and recreate the secret.

#Code for getting queue names of namespace:

```
Get-AzServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroupName mygroup -NamespaceName mybus |
ForEach-Object {
Get-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Namespace $_.Name |
ForEach-Object {
[PsCustomObject\]@{
Queue = $\_.Name
}}}
```

Comment: I tried and got the script at last:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and got the script at last. This code will truncate entity path from alias connection string and send it to the keyvault.

```
    $ResourceGroup = ******* define yours as per requirement
    $rg = $ResourceGroup
    $ns = ($ResourceGroup, "bus", "abc" -join '-').ToLower() 
    $kv = ("ABC", $EnvironmentName, $EnvironmentInstance, "key" -join '-').ToLower()
    Get-AzServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroup $rg -NamespaceName $ns |
     ForEach-Object {
      Foreach ($i in $_.Name) {
       Get-AzServiceBusAuthorizationRule -ResourceGroupName $rg -NamespaceName $ns -QueueName $_.Name |
        ForEach-Object {
         Get-AzServiceBusKey -ResourceGroupName $rg -NamespaceName $ns -QueueName $i -Name $_.name |
          ForEach-Object {   
           $secretname = $_.KeyName + '-alias'
           $secretvalue = $_.PrimaryConnectionString -replace ";EntityPath.*",""  
                                                                       
           Write-Host "adding latest secret value for $secretname"                                                                          
           $vaultsecret = ConvertTo-SecureString $secretvalue -AsPlainText -Force
           Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $kv -Name $secretname -SecretValue $vaultsecret
           Write-Host "$secretname added to keyvault $kv"
           }
         }
       }
    }
```